# Shell script internally call another shell script and doesnot return the ouput to main script when i use the external table

Tags: oracle, shell

My main script api_call.sh internally calls config.sh and should pass the parameter value to the main script.
The script works fine when I execute it in Linux. But when I queries through external table the second script does not return the output to the main script.

Can anyone please tell me.
Do I need to specify the location when I call the second script when I queried via external table..?
And how can I return the value from the second script to the first one.

Script1: apicall.sh

```
export SourceName FileName
    . ./config.sh "$SourceName" "$FileName"
```

get the application type from the config file to the main script
    v_application_type=$application_type

Script2: config.sh

```
while :
do
        case $1 in
                xxx)
                                                              application_type=application/json        
                        done
                        break
                        ;;
                *)
                        paramexist=0
                        break
                        ;;
        esac
done

CREATE TABLE XXX_XT
(
  SCRIPT_OUTPUT  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY TMP_DIR
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        preprocessor edw_bin_dir : 'apicall.sh'
        skip 1
        LOGFILE LOG_DIR:'api_call_xt.log'
        fields terminated by ','
       )
     LOCATION (TMP_DIR:'xxx.json')
  )
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED
PARALLEL ( DEGREE DEFAULT INSTANCES DEFAULT );
```

Comment: how are you running the query/sql statements? I don't even see a sqlplus connection in the script.

Comment: @Ajitha : You are exporting two variables, but you never use them in a child process. Hence you can drop your `export` command. Also I don't see that you provide values for `SourceName` and  `FileName` (but maybe this is in a part of `apicall.sh` which you didn't show here).

Comment: Am running select XT table sql in oracle where in the preprocessor section am using the apicall.sh script. so when I run sql the xt table ran the shell script.

Comment: Two variables from the main script actually passed the parameter to the child process and using it in case statement $1 and $2 I haven't pasted the script relates to $2 that is filename. sourcename and filename am passing it as input when I run the script. The script run well if I ran in Linux environment  but when I ran the same script through external table it behaves differently